# Robust regression is not helping?

Tags: r, multiple-regression, outliers

I have run multiple linear regression, using data set with several outliers.

`M <- lm(data = data, y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4)`

As a result, I have obtained qqplot with severely skewed points:
[image]

In order to handle this problem, I have decided to perform robust regression, using MASS package in R (*function rlm()*):

`M2 <- rlm(data = data, y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4, psi = psi.bisquare, method = "MM")`

I have tried different psi options, nevertheless, the situation has not been improved. Here is the plot of residuals after performing rlm:
[image]

Here you can observe residuals of each model:

              `M1          M2
1  -137.04722588 -214.973859
2   -33.43130307  -66.905413
3   -21.18130354  -47.616570
4   -31.17663230  -46.675170
5   -61.70080246 -140.090111
6   102.07968977    7.007476
7   103.33823930   16.683338
8    15.39766942   13.711492
9   106.26112820  165.321581
10   21.83596732   79.429042
11   -9.13696772    3.837210
12  -12.36280158   -8.363608
13  -20.90424085    5.349618
14    7.78673175    8.429199
15   -1.70692031   -1.010752
16   -4.92790026   -6.948873
17  -18.16543421   30.779084
18  -61.95627364  -12.745194
19   12.64171239  -10.948301
20    6.61833665   -4.250177
21   17.86133209  -11.388349
22   29.71830306   15.984221
23   -2.33080090    3.450663
24   -0.65863284   -6.448036
25    3.04566111    6.343600
26   -9.47940313    2.811655
27   28.17267117   24.025434
28   12.67731281   -2.253812
29  -29.77107684  -25.641591
30   -0.09152992    7.508937
31   -2.75539351    0.907238
32   -8.65011210   -5.355938`

**My data set**:

`y   x1   x2   x3   x4
1   230  918 1152 232  647
2    80  299  376  77  219
3    47  192  234  50  148
4    36  157  172  35  109
5   165  668  807 153  506
6    76  225  512  85  251
7    55  157  451  62  188
8   135  211  176  48  129
9  1089 1657 1415 355  933
10  595  894  671 162  456
11  165  271  207  49  138
12  104  184  149  45  104
13  446  777  599 183  460
14  214  367  272  90  238
15  146  255  177  65  166
16   99  182  123  45  120
17  566  937  542 207  561
18  303  517  238 108  275
19  117  244  203  86  209
20  102  177  167  82  144
21  747 1427 1092 431 1055
22  374  622  568 270  482
23  243  375  390 190  265
24  158  251  319 155  194
25  769 1212 1551 703  891
26  375  580  668 311  404
27  278  400  513 225  292
28  170  282  388 153  215
29  786 1350 1642 634  925
30  338  532  631 245  348`

I would appreciate any help and thoughts. I am new to data science and R, so it is quite possible that I am missing something essential. May be I should implement my own weights instead of using auto function or, in this case, rlm is not the solution at all. I also would like to mention that this regression is going to be used only for interpretation purposes, however, I still want to resolve the issue with outliers. Thanks for reading!

Comment: Robust methods will not make outliers go away.  In fact, they tend to make the outliers look even *further* from the data before, because they reduce (or even entirely eliminate) the influence of the outliers on the fit.

Comment: @whuber, Thanks for your answer. I understand that they will not go away, I have thought that rlm should adjust their infulence on the regression model. Should I relay on qqplot, for example. I want to understand is the regression model has become any better?

Comment: It all depends on what you might mean by "better"! Usually the best you can realistically hope for is a model that fits the *non-outlying* data very well.

Comment: I'm a bit skeptic because all your `y` values are integer numbers. Are those counts?

Comment: @whuber, Better from a statistical inference, getting normal distribution, for example, if it is possible. (I know that I can adjust data, using Box-Cox transformation, but I want to keep interpetation of my results).

Comment: @Roland, no. Those are days :)

Comment: Do you mean durations in days? I'm suspecting you should use some kind of GLM.

Comment: Getting a Normal distribution should almost never be an objective of a statistical analysis.  It's usually impossible, almost always meaningless, and rarely helpful.  The Normal distribution is the Procrustean Bed of statistics: some practitioners would stretch their data or cut off the head and feet of their data to make them look Normal, when the data are best left to lie alone!

Comment: @Roland, yes durations. I will read about GLM, I have heard about it, however, I know a little.

Comment: @whuber, what about getting reliable t-values for my variables. I thought i need normality to check different statistics.Maybe I am completely wrong. However, when I explain the results to other people, I would like to prove my them somehow.

Comment: *I would like to prove them somehow

Comment: You abandoned that idea of getting reliable t-values when you resorted to robust regression: you moved into an *exploratory* mode.  If you need to test coefficients, then you need a procedure that accounts correctly for how you are modeling your outliers.  With enough data, bootstrapping will do that.

Comment: @whuber, thanks a lot for your help. Do you know any other ways to deal with this problem? My data is a time series and I have only 32. My main purpose to explain how Xi influence my Y.

Comment: Methods of multivariate time series analysis would be most appropriate.  Unfortunately, you have a very short dataset.  Even simple regression models tend to be highly uncertain when the ratio of observations to explanatory variables is as low as yours (32:4=8) and that problem will only get worse if you introduce yet more parameters into the model.

Comment: Yes, I assume that my data set is the main problem (as well as lack of knowledge). One more thing... is it possible to use usual regression, just to give some approximate explanation of my independent variables? Or this approach is a fraud.